# Clone specific folder from git repository without the subfolder structure

Tags: git

Let's say I have a repository with this structure:

```
A/B/file1
A/B/file2
A/C/file3
D/E/file4
D/F/file5
```

I want to checkout the content of A/B/ in my local folder my/local/folder but I don't want the subdirectory structure which is what you get with sparse-checkout.

The end result should NOT be:

```
my/local/folder/A/B/file1
my/local/folder/A/B/file2
```

but

```
my/local/folder/file1
my/local/folder/file2
```

How can you do that with GIT?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your working directory clean with just the selected files on it, you have to start from zero.

First you need to clone the repository avoiding checking out any file. You can accomplish this using the `-n` argument of the `clone` command:

```
git clone -n path/to/repo.git
```

Then you can pick the specific file you want to check out by running this command:

```
git checkout HEAD:path/to/file filename
```

Or you just checkout all the files in the provided folder by changing the file name to `*`:

```
git checkout HEAD:path/to/file *
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it but it created the folder structure as in the repository. I want the folder content straight under my folder in the file system.

Comment: Skipping the folder structure of the project, just the single file?

Comment: I have edited my question. Maybe it wasn't clear enough. I want the full content of the subdirectory straight under my target folder in my local filesystem.

Comment: @user275475 check it now, i added the exception to checkout all the files inside a folder.